# VS TACO Update 6: Could not find module 'umask'

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

(*Looking for the solution? Check the bottom of this question for the solution*)

Updated to the latest Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova to Update 6, but still have some issue with latest Node.JS installed (v5.6.0).

Creating a new empty project and building the first time, gives this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.6.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.34
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed.
1>  module.js:341
1>      throw err;
1>      ^
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'umask'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
1>      at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\umask.js:1:75)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
1>      at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Then running the Clear Cordova Cache, this was the output:

```
Clearing Apache Cordova cache...
Removing package vs-tac ...
Removing package vs-npm ...
Completed
```

Restarting, opening same empty project and building, gave the following output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-npm\2.14.9\npm -> C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-npm\2.14.9\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1>  C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-npm\2.14.9
1>  `-- npm@2.14.9
1>    +-- abbrev@1.0.7
1>    +-- ansi@0.3.0
1>    +-- ansicolors@0.3.2
1>    +-- ansistyles@0.1.3
1>    +-- archy@1.0.0
1>    +-- async-some@1.0.2
1>    +-- block-stream@0.0.8
1>    +-- char-spinner@1.0.1
1>    +-- chmodr@1.0.2
1>    +-- chownr@1.0.1
1>    +-- cmd-shim@2.0.1
1>    | `-- graceful-fs@3.0.8
1>    +-- columnify@1.5.2
1>    | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.0
1>    | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
1>    | `-- wcwidth@1.0.0
1>    |   `-- defaults@1.0.2
1>    |     `-- clone@0.1.19
1>    +-- config-chain@1.1.9
1>    | `-- proto-list@1.2.4
1>    +-- dezalgo@1.0.3
1>    | `-- asap@2.0.3
1>    +-- editor@1.0.0
1>    +-- fs-vacuum@1.2.7
1>    +-- fs-write-stream-atomic@1.0.4
1>    +-- fstream@1.0.8
1>    +-- fstream-npm@1.0.5
1>    | `-- fstream-ignore@1.0.3
1>    +-- github-url-from-git@1.4.0
1>    +-- github-url-from-username-repo@1.0.2
1>    +-- glob@5.0.15
1>    | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0
1>    +-- graceful-fs@4.1.2
1>    +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.4
1>    +-- inflight@1.0.4
1>    +-- inherits@2.0.1
1>    +-- ini@1.3.4
1>    +-- init-package-json@1.9.1
1>    | `-- promzard@0.3.0
1>    +-- lockfile@1.0.1
1>    +-- lru-cache@2.7.0
1>    +-- minimatch@3.0.0
1>    | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.1
1>    |   +-- balanced-match@0.2.1
1>    |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
1>    +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
1>    | `-- minimist@0.0.8
1>    +-- node-gyp@3.0.3
1>    | +-- glob@4.5.3
1>    | | `-- minimatch@2.0.10
1>    | |   `-- brace-expansion@1.1.0
1>    | |     +-- balanced-match@0.2.0
1>    | |     `-- concat-map@0.0.1
1>    | +-- minimatch@1.0.0
1>    | | `-- sigmund@1.0.1
1>    | +-- path-array@1.0.0
1>    | | `-- array-index@0.1.1
1>    | |   `-- debug@2.2.0
1>    | |     `-- ms@0.7.1
1>    | `-- tar@1.0.3
1>    +-- nopt@3.0.4
1>    +-- normalize-git-url@3.0.1
1>    +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.4
1>    | `-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0
1>    |   `-- builtin-modules@1.1.0
1>    +-- npm-cache-filename@1.0.2
1>    +-- npm-install-checks@1.0.6
1>    +-- npm-package-arg@4.0.2
1>    +-- npm-registry-client@7.0.7
1>    | +-- concat-stream@1.5.0
1>    | | +-- readable-stream@2.0.2
1>    | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    | | | +-- isarray@0.0.1
1>    | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.3
1>    | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
1>    | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.1
1>    | | `-- typedarray@0.0.6
1>    | `-- npmlog@2.0.2
1>    |   +-- ansi@0.3.1
1>    |   +-- are-we-there-yet@1.0.6
1>    |   | `-- delegates@1.0.0
1>    |   `-- gauge@1.2.5
1>    |     +-- has-unicode@2.0.0
1>    |     +-- lodash.pad@3.3.0
1>    |     | +-- lodash._root@3.0.0
1>    |     | `-- lodash.repeat@3.2.0
1>    |     +-- lodash.padleft@3.1.1
1>    |     | +-- lodash._basetostring@3.0.1
1>    |     | `-- lodash._createpadding@3.6.1
1>    |     `-- lodash.padright@3.1.1
1>    +-- npm-user-validate@0.1.2
1>    +-- npmlog@1.2.1
1>    | +-- are-we-there-yet@1.0.4
1>    | | `-- delegates@0.1.0
1>    | `-- gauge@1.2.0
1>    |   +-- has-unicode@1.0.0
1>    |   +-- lodash.pad@3.1.0
1>    |   | +-- lodash._basetostring@3.0.0
1>    |   | `-- lodash._createpadding@3.6.0
1>    |   |   `-- lodash.repeat@3.0.0
1>    |   +-- lodash.padleft@3.1.1
1>    |   `-- lodash.padright@3.1.1
1>    +-- once@1.3.2
1>    +-- opener@1.4.1
1>    +-- osenv@0.1.3
1>    | +-- os-homedir@1.0.0
1>    | `-- os-tmpdir@1.0.1
1>    +-- path-is-inside@1.0.1
1>    +-- read@1.0.7
1>    | `-- mute-stream@0.0.5
1>    +-- read-installed@4.0.3
1>    | +-- debuglog@1.0.1
1>    | +-- readdir-scoped-modules@1.0.2
1>    | `-- util-extend@1.0.1
1>    +-- read-package-json@2.0.1
1>    | `-- json-parse-helpfulerror@1.0.3
1>    |   `-- jju@1.2.0
1>    +-- readable-stream@1.1.13
1>    | +-- core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    | +-- isarray@0.0.1
1>    | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31
1>    +-- realize-package-specifier@3.0.1
1>    +-- request@2.65.0
1>    | +-- aws-sign2@0.6.0
1>    | +-- bl@1.0.0
1>    | | `-- readable-stream@2.0.3
1>    | |   +-- core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    | |   +-- isarray@0.0.1
1>    | |   +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.3
1>    | |   +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
1>    | |   `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
1>    | +-- caseless@0.11.0
1>    | +-- combined-stream@1.0.5
1>    | | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0
1>    | +-- extend@3.0.0
1>    | +-- forever-agent@0.6.1
1>    | +-- form-data@1.0.0-rc3
1>    | | `-- async@1.5.0
1>    | +-- har-validator@2.0.2
1>    | | +-- chalk@1.1.1
1>    | | | +-- ansi-styles@2.1.0
1>    | | | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
1>    | | | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
1>    | | | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
1>    | | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.0
1>    | | | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
1>    | | | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
1>    | | +-- commander@2.9.0
1>    | | | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1
1>    | | +-- is-my-json-valid@2.12.2
1>    | | | +-- generate-function@2.0.0
1>    | | | +-- generate-object-property@1.2.0
1>    | | | | `-- is-property@1.0.2
1>    | | | +-- jsonpointer@2.0.0
1>    | | | `-- xtend@4.0.0
1>    | | `-- pinkie-promise@1.0.0
1>    | |   `-- pinkie@1.0.0
1>    | +-- hawk@3.1.0
1>    | | +-- boom@2.10.0
1>    | | +-- cryptiles@2.0.5
1>    | | +-- hoek@2.16.3
1>    | | `-- sntp@1.0.9
1>    | +-- http-signature@0.11.0
1>    | | +-- asn1@0.1.11
1>    | | +-- assert-plus@0.1.5
1>    | | `-- ctype@0.5.3
1>    | +-- isstream@0.1.2
1>    | +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
1>    | +-- mime-types@2.1.7
1>    | | `-- mime-db@1.19.0
1>    | +-- node-uuid@1.4.3
1>    | +-- oauth-sign@0.8.0
1>    | +-- qs@5.2.0
1>    | +-- stringstream@0.0.5
1>    | +-- tough-cookie@2.2.0
1>    | `-- tunnel-agent@0.4.1
1>    +-- retry@0.8.0
1>    +-- rimraf@2.4.3
1>    +-- semver@5.0.3
1>    +-- sha@2.0.1
1>    | `-- readable-stream@2.0.2
1>    |   +-- core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    |   +-- isarray@0.0.1
1>    |   +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.3
1>    |   +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
1>    |   `-- util-deprecate@1.0.1
1>    +-- slide@1.1.6
1>    +-- sorted-object@1.0.0
1>    +-- spdx@0.4.1
1>    | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.0.1
1>    +-- tar@2.2.1
1>    +-- text-table@0.2.0
1>    +-- uid-number@0.0.6
1>    +-- umask@1.1.0
1>    +-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
1>    | +-- spdx-correct@1.0.1
1>    | | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.0.2
1>    | `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.0
1>    |   +-- spdx-exceptions@1.0.2
1>    |   `-- spdx-license-ids@1.0.2
1>    +-- validate-npm-package-name@2.2.2
1>    | `-- builtins@0.0.7
1>    +-- which@1.2.0
1>    | `-- is-absolute@0.1.7
1>    |   `-- is-relative@0.1.3
1>    +-- wrappy@1.0.1
1>    `-- write-file-atomic@1.1.3
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.6.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.34
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  > edge-cs@0.3.0 install C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge\node_modules\edge-cs
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  > edge@5.0.0 install C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v5.6.0
1>  C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires glob@'~5.0.15' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\glob,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.6
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires graceful-fs@'~4.1.2' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\graceful-fs,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.8
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires lru-cache@'~3.2.0' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\lru-cache,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.7.3
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires minimatch@'~3.0.0' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\minimatch,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.0
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires nopt@'~3.0.6' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\nopt,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.1
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires request@'~2.67.0' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.47.0
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires rimraf@'~2.4.4' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\rimraf,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires semver@'~5.1.0' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\semver,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.3.6
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires tar@'~2.2.1' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\tar,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.2
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm requires uid-number@'0.0.6' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\uid-number,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.0.5
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\form-data requires async@'~0.9.0' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\async,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.4.2
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\hash-files requires async@'0.x.x' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\async,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.4.2
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\hash-files requires glob@'3.x.x' but will load
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\glob,
1>  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.15
1>  vs-tac@1.0.34 C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>  ├── semver@2.3.1
1>  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
1>  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5)
1>  ├── fstream@1.0.8 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@4.1.3, mkdirp@0.5.1)
1>  ├── request@2.36.0 (aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, tough-cookie@2.2.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.0.0)
1>  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@0.1.31)
1>  ├── vs-libimobile@0.0.2
1>  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.32 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, open@0.0.3, accounting@0.4.1, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0)
1>  └── edge@5.0.0 (nan@2.2.0, edge-cs@0.3.0)
1>  ------ npm install of vs-tac@1.0.34 from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac completed.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed.
1>  module.js:341
1>      throw err;
1>      ^
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'umask'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
1>      at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\umask.js:1:75)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
1>      at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

For my Visual Studio options, I have moved the $(PATH) variable to the top in the "External Web Tools", so VS uses the globally installed version of Node.JS.

There is a umask package located in the vs-npm:

C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-npm\2.14.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\umask

There are no umask in the vs-tac module folder, as there is no dependency on the package.json on that.

First I ran "npm install taco-cli -g".

Then I ran "npm install umask -g", which returned missing npmlog package. Then ran "npm install npmlog -g" and built the project again. Resulting in this error output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.6.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.34
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed.
1>  C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:19
1>    , fs = gfs.gracefulify(require('fs'))
1>               ^
1>
1>  TypeError: gfs.gracefulify is not a function
1>      at C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:19:14
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:469:3)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
1>      at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
1>      at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sondr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js:27:21)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This error occurs in the cordova folder, so I figured perhaps the issue was now related to cordova and tried "npm install cordova -g".

And then... it works!

Answer (score 5):

So if anyone else have a similar issue, try the following:

```
npm install cordova -g
```

If that does not help, run all these commands and see if you have the same luck:

```
npm install taco-cli -g
npm install umask -g
npm install npmlog -g
npm install cordova -g
```

Running the cordova command will install version 6 of Cordova, which the Update 6 should be compatible with. I was running 5.4.1 (I think) previously.

Comment: The command will install latest cordova version, not "version 6".